# Is there a way to get the value of a crypto in another one with uniswap

Tags: ethereum, blockchain, cryptocurrency, uniswap

Im a beginner in the blockchain/crypto world and I was wondering if there is a way to get the value of a crypto in another one on uniswap (like in the image where we can see that on uniswap 1 ETH = 2997 1INCH). , like using the SDK or the Router ecc.. If you have any suggestion please help me.

[image: 1]

I tried using the uniswap sdk and the smart contracts periphery contracts but i couldn't find nothing that could help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. You can get the price of a cryptocurrency as it is traded in Uniswap.

- For Uniswp v2 like exchanges, the price can be calculated as a ratio of reverse0 / reserve1
- The related smart contract call is `pair.getReserves`
- For more complete example, you can read the source code of [get_current_mid_price() function here](https://web3-ethereum-defi.readthedocs.io/api/_autosummary_uniswap_v2/eth_defi.uniswap_v2.pair.PairDetails.html#eth_defi.uniswap_v2.pair.PairDetails.get_current_mid_price)
- For Uniswap v3, it is there are similar helper functions in Uniswap perihelia contracts